# sys.dm_exec_query_stats does not have permission as SA

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the following script, to check the last run sql script:

`SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS dest 
WHERE dest.TEXT LIKE '%Drop%'`

but for this :
    `select * from sys.dm_exec_query_statse`

It says 
"The user does not have permission to perform this action."

I am logged in as SA, so why I still do not have permission?

edit: logout, login, new query window... tadaaam, everything works -.-

Comment: Are you literally opening a fresh query window to SQL Server in SSMS and running just the above code? It's not (say) inside a stored procedure, or anything like that?

Comment: Yes I open a fresh query window, and run it there as sa

Comment: And that's why I asked whether you were doing this in a fresh query window - there are plenty of things you can do that will leave your connection in an odd state, even if it started out with you running as `sa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `sys.fn_my_permissions` DMF get list of permission you acount has,and `SUSER_NAME()` to get login name that is executing query

Comment: I don't think `sa` can be removed from `sysadmin`. `alter server role sysadmin drop member sa` produces `Cannot use the special principal 'sa'.`

Comment: I ran "select SUSER_NAME()" and it resulted a normal user, not sa... but I logged in with my sa, so I don't understand

Comment: Hmm...,try to use explicitly set EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa'(or revert) before executing query(in same query window) and see what happens ?

Comment: Msg 15406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "sa" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Comment: You are definitely not logged as sa user.Can you write exactly step by step what are you doing ?

Comment: Lol... now I logged in again, openned a new query window and I am sa now, and can execute the command. Thank you for your help, this SUSER_NAME() was useful (maybe I still used an old query window from another account ? )